# Nested ExpandableListView with Custom BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I'm working on a project that has an `ExpandableListView` nested inside a regular `ListView`. I think I have over complicated my data/view structures. The reason for doing this is because I'm using this [**viewflow**](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) library which requires my views be in a `ListView`. Inside my main layout `View` (which from here will be referred to as a page that go's into the viewflow `ListView`) I have an `ExpandableListView`. This is all made more complicated by the fact that the pages views are created in code and not separate view activities. Here's some diagrams to help make it a little clearer.

[image: Hope this helps!]

I want to get the data from here

[image: and this]

I can get all my information displaying correctly for each of the individually, code created pages. The problem is that I am unsure of how I can retrieve the data held inside the `ExpandableListView` for each of the pages. I've tried keeping track off all the `ExpandableListViews` generated in an `ArrayList` then looping through it to create the `OnChildClickListeners`. The code compiles and runs fine but the click listener is never called.

My first guess is that since the pages are being created programmatically (thus so are the `ExpandableListViews`) their IDs are being changed and so the click listener is being registered else where.

Some code you say! Well I'm not too sure what code I need to provide and to paste it all would be ridiculous. If there is a section you would like to have a look at (for example the page generation) just let me know and I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working by getting the `ExpandableListView` by ID in my custom `ListView` controller. I then passed the *viewflow* `ListView` my custom controller which I could then access from the top level. In theory the idea was to pass everything back one level and in the end it got there!